# GUI for DFT calculations

Tags: software, dipole-moment, density-functional-theory

I am a beginner in DFT.
Can someone suggest a good DFT software with a GUI for simulating dipole moment directions and optical absorption spectra in an organic crystal?
I have tried Burai. But it doesn't seem to have this functionality.
I have heard about the Amsterdam modeling suite. Does any of you have experience with that software?

Comment: Also note there is the [Matter Modeling Stack Exhange](https://mattermodelling.stackexchange.com)

Comment: Thank you Nihar.